# Why is Math.Cos returning the wrong value?

Tags: c#, math, xna

In my code:

```
Vector2 colCircle = new Vector2();

colCircle = new Vector2((R * Math.Sin(D)), -(R * Math.Cos(D)));
```

While:

```
R = 22.627
D = 89.214
```

When checked on my calculator, the X value is correct, but the Y value should be -0.310 but in program it is -7.134.

Any ideas why?

Comment: I can't duplicate your values, but it might help to know that the .net trig functions (as in most math library implementations) expect angle parameters in radians.

Comment: I think it's interesting how close the programs X value was to the actual one with radians.

Comment: _I think it's interesting how close the programs X value was to the actual one with radians._ The sine function is maximal, `+1`, at the angle `28.5 * π` radians exactly. That's `89.535` radians.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The trigonometric functions expect radians, not degrees.

Comment: Indeed. Ugh... Thats completely dumb of me.

Comment: Yes - 2 Pi (rad)  = 360 (degrees)

Comment: So why Math.Cos(90 * Math.Pi / 180) return some *weird value instead of 0?

Answer (score 4):

Replace what you have with

```
colCircle = new Vector2((R * Math.Sin(D*Math.PI/180.0)), -(R * Math.Cos(D*Math.PI/180.0)));
```

and you should be fine.  Cos/Sin are expecting radians not degrees.

Comment: Actually, MathHelper.ToRadians was quicker to implement.