# javascript math.cos error / Math.cos() delivers wrong result

Tags: javascript

the actual value of cos(15) is 0.9659258262890682867497431997289. but when i entered Math.cos(15) int the Google Chrome console, it's showing -0.7596879128588205 as the result. Why would it show this error? Why can't JavaScript return 0.9659258262890682867497431997289?

Comment: and [Why is Math.Cos returning the wrong value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4168151/218196)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Math.cos` takes its argument in *radians*. Thus, you first need to convert the 15 degrees to radians before calling `Math.cos`

```
var degrees = 15;
var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
var cosOf15 = Math.cos(radians);
```

Comment: I wonder why this got downvoted. Looks correct to me.

Answer (score 5):

-.759 is when the argument is in radians, .965 is when it's in degrees. All you have to do is convert to radians to get the result you want.

Comment: is this enough? `(Math.cos(15)*(180/Math.PI))`

Comment: This won't work. The result of `Math.cos` is not in radians, it's the *argument* that's in radians!

Comment: Multiply 15, not the cosine of 15, by 180/pi

Comment: Again, no. You need to convert degrees to radians, so you multiply by pi/180. I'd recommend you give your answer a quick test before posting it...